# R: determine whether a simple function uses a variable

Tags: r

Is there a way that I can determine whether a simple function uses a variable? For example, I have two variables `a` and `b`, and a function `fun` that uses the variable `a` but not `b`.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2

fun <- function(x){
  a * x
}

somecheck(fun, a)
#> TRUE

somecheck(fun, b)
#> FALSE
```

Comment: The duplicate shows how to get a list of all the free variables in a function. You can just check if your variable of interest is in that list. So you could write this function as `somecheck <- function(fun, v) deparse(substitute(v)) %in% codetools::findGlobals(fun)`